# php - performance of continue state

Tags: php, loops, continue, micro-optimization

I was thinking today at work: is there a much faster way to get results using `continue` state?

```
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    if (!($i % 2)) {
        continue;
    }
    do_something_odd($i);
}
```

Is faster ordinary loop with *if/else* or is it faster skipping results using continue?

I am asking because performance and optimizaton.

Comment: It's going to be a very little difference, so I'd rather focus on optimizing things that actually matter. That being said though, if you just want odd numbers, you can do `$i+2` instead of `$i++`.

Comment: @Qirel I know for mathematical loops like `$i+2` but I put this like example. I thinking when you work on real loops with bunch of data, many loops inside loop, how mutch will be faster and what?

Comment: Actually, what I posted was wrong, the syntax is `$i+=2`, not `$i+2`. Though if you want to test which one is faster, just run a benchmark.

Comment: I think readability matters much more in PHP. I'm a fan of `if($i % 2 == 0)continue;` over negation like `if (!($i % 2))` and prefer early exiting over if/else. That being said, run a benchmark and tell us your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for answer, anyway:

in general, there is no performance difference between:

```
for (...) {
    if (condition) continue;
    some work;
}
```

and

```
for (...) {
    if (!condition) some work;
}
```

I suggest to avoid `continue`, only because I suppose it is less readable, it is basically `goto`.

Of course first thing to optimize is high level algorithms, data structure and so on. If you done with it and you need to maximize performance - the main enemy is condition/branch and mis-predictions. There are many different techniques for that:

1. Move condition outside the loop if it is possible
2. Split loop into multiple ones
3. Usually multiplication, division and modulus are quite slow, in comparison to bit wise operators
4. Some conditions can be replaced with branchless statements
5. Un-rool loops to minimize number of tests

**Measure every change**

For example slightly modified version of your code to calculate number of even and odd numbers in range [-N,N], excluding 0:

```
define('N', 100000000);

$start = microtime(true);

$odd_count = 0;
$even_count = 0;
for ($i=-N; $i<=N; $i++)
    if ($i != 0)
        if ($i % 2 != 0) $odd_count++;
        else $even_count++;

$end = microtime(true);

echo 'odd: '.$odd_count."\n";
echo 'even: '.$even_count."\n";
echo 'time: '.($end-$start)."\n";
```

Of course we can replace this whole loop with simple formula (it is high level algorithm optimization), but lets try to work with loop:

Average time on my host across multiple runs: 9.1 sec

Apply 1st and 2nd rule:

```
for ($i=-N; $i<0; $i++)
        if ($i % 2 != 0) $odd_count++;
        else $even_count++;
for ($i=1; $i<=N; $i++)
        if ($i % 2 != 0) $odd_count++;
        else $even_count++;
```

Time: 7.7 sec

Apply 3rd and 4th rule:

```
for ($i=-N; $i<0; $i++) {
    $t = $i & 1;
    $odd_count += $t;
    $even_count += 1 - $t;
}
for ($i=1; $i<=N; $i++) {
    $t = $i & 1;
    $odd_count += $t;
    $even_count += 1 - $t;
}
```

Time: 7.3 sec

And final result:

```
for ($i=-N; $i<0;) {
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
}
for ($i=1; $i<=N;) {
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
    $t = $i++ & 1; $odd_count += $t; $even_count += 1 - $t;
}
```

Time: 7.0 sec

Comment: Interesting, in PHP 7 I find that your 2nd test is faster than others. The last test (7.0) for me running 9.57s  and 2nd for 8.2s.In PHP5.6 is like you describe. Interesting!

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić its possible that php7 introduced some optimization which made `if %` faster then `&` or it could be bug which made `&` slower then `if %` :) I'd try to use `(int)` casting. Anyway, this is why you have to measure everything